# Display a <div> only once while looping and displaying other data in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a use case where am displaying options with the help of a `loop`.

I need to display the text `suggestions` only once for the entire `loop cycle`. The code block `number.imageUrl` may repeat but the `suggestions` text should be displayed only once.

```
const listItems = numbers.map((number) => 

<li>

{number.imageUrl && 

<div>suggestions</div>

<div>{number.imageUrl}</div>

}
<div>number.text</div>

</li>

);
```

Comment: Move that div out of loop. Or `if (i == 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346234/justinas) said, either move `<div>suggestions</div>` out of the map function, or do this:

```js
const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) => (
  <li>
    {index === 0 && <div>suggestions</div>}
    {number.imageUrl && <div>{number.imageUrl}</div>}
    <div>{number.text}</div>
  </li>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) =>

{number.imageUrl &&

{

index === 0 && suggestions

}

{number.imageUrl}

}

number.text

);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).